# Compiling Java in terminal gives illegal character errors within a string

Tags: java, string

I am new and just trying to do the most basic of all, simple 'Hello World'

Here is the code, The same you find anywhere:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
    }
}
```

When I run in the terminal (I use a Mac) I am posed with the following errors:

```
HelloWorld.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
    System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
                       ^
HelloWorld.java:3: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
                        ^
HelloWorld.java:3: error: not a statement
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
                                  ^
HelloWorld.java:3: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
                                       ^
HelloWorld.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
                                        ^
5 errors
```

What is going on here? All the errors are the string!

Comment: I assume that you just copy-paste this code from some pdf where `"` and `”` are often printed as `“`. Unfortunately these characters are not the same and only `"` is valid so you need to replace each `“`and `”` with `"`. (Psst: don't use short-cuts if you are learning something new, instead of copying write code yourself, I know it takes more time but it is worth it).

Comment: You're using "smart quotes" instead of regular quotes. Don't know if you copied and pasted code from a website, or used a bizarre editor, but simply replacing these quotes with the character that the `"` key outputs will make things fine. Make sure to use a real text editor, and not some word processor, to write code.

Answer (score 5):

`“` is the wrong character to use to denote a string - you should use `"`.

Comment: Thanks, the editor changed my quotes to 'smart quotes'

Answer (score 3):

`“”` is not valid String, use `""`. At your code, Change from

```
 System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
```

To,

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed my editor and re-saved it and it worked... I'm not sure why the quotation marks are different between the two

Comment: @DavidGriffith, Yes, these are different. You can check their different ASCII value using  `System.out.println((int)'”');` and `System.out.println((int)'"');`

Comment: Thanks, the editor changed my quotes to 'smart quotes', I've fixed it to not do this anymore

Answer (score 0):

“ is different from " in Java.

You need to replace “Hello World!” with "Hello World!"

Comment: Thanks, the editor changed my quotes to 'smart quotes' , I've got it fixed to not do this anymore