# Error compiling Java code written in TextEdit: Illegal character 8218

Tags: java, macos

I am beginning to learn how to develop Java programs on a Mac OS/X Yosemite system. I've downloaded the JDK and JRE from the relevant websites and written my first program using TextEdit:

```
public class MyFirstApp
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println(“I Rule!”); 
        System.out.println(“The World”);
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile, I got the following errors:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should change the “ and ” characters with the " character.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719591/compiling-java-in-terminal-gives-illegal-character-errors-within-a-string

Comment: Don't use TextEdit. You probably saved as RTF, which is why you got the wrong quote marks. Get something good like Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the curly quote with a normal quote i.e: `“` to `"`.
This usually happens when you copy and paste code from rich text source like a word document or PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You are source code which has replaced double quotes with equivalent but more fancy unicode characters showing start and stop of the quote.  Most likely because you copied the code from a web page not presenting code snippets correctly or using an editor not intended for source code.

You must replace these fancy quotes with the simple,  normal quotes ( `"` and `'`) and recompile.  Consult a Java tutorial to learn which ones to use when.