# Illegal character \u201c

Tags: java

While compiling this I got an error. As well as I am still confused if I can create the object Overload before actually writing methods and declaring the variables.

```
 class Overload {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Overload overload = new Overload();
    Overload.methodOne();
    Overload.methodOne( 8 );
}

    void methodOne() {
    System.out.println(“no arguments”);
}

    void methodOne( int x) {
    System.out.println(“ integer value=” + x );
}

}
```

At line I got an error illegal character:

> '\u201c'

Comment: There are no line numbers, can you please tell us which lines 6 and 8 are?

Comment: Count it from the beginning of the code na :)

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Please use the search function prior to asking a question: [SO query: java illegal character \u201c](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+Illegal+character+%5Cu201c). All listed results solve your problem. For example: [Compiling Java in terminal gives illegal character errors within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719591/2411243)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you should us the this double quote `"`, instead of this one `“`.

Second you should use the object name to invoke the method. Use `overload` instead of `Overload` (notice the case sensitivity)

Here is a working version of your code:

```
public class Overload {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Overload overload = new Overload();
        overload.methodOne();
        overload.methodOne(8);
    }
    void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("no arguments");
    }    
    void methodOne(int x) {
        System.out.println("integer value=" + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong quote character. You must use the simple double quote `"`, and you are using the unicode character '\u201c' `“` instead. It's probably your editor biting you.